# Compose: set absolute position of the child element

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

In this simple example I have a box inside a parent box.
I need to update the position of the child box.
I tried different modifiers, but the offset is not applied:

```
        Box (modifier = Modifier
        .background(Color.LightGray)
        .size(800.dp)
        ){
        Box(modifier = Modifier
            .background(Color.Red)
            .size(40.dp)
            .offset (x = 100.dp, y = 100.dp)
        )
    }
```

**Edit**

Working solution for me now is to call offset() fun before size()

Answer (score 0):

```
Box(modifier = Modifier.background(Color.LightGray).size(800.dp)) {
Box(modifier = Modifier.size(800.dp)) { // Inner box with constraints
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .background(Color.Red)
            .size(40.dp)
            .offset(x = 100.dp, y = 100.dp)
    )
}
```

Creates an additional Box with explicit sizing, providing a constrained layout for the offset modifier to work effectively.

Comment: Thanks! Since it did not work for me, I looked into modifiers ordering, and it turned out offset should go before setting size